# Передача значения переменной в XML.Nodes в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, sql-server, xquery

Например, есть такой код:

```
    DECLARE @XML XML='<root>
                <TableRow>
                    <Name>TT1</Name>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <Name>TT2</Name>
                </TableRow>
                </root>'
DECLARE @Xpath NVARCHAR(255)='root/TableRow'

SELECT a.e.value('(Name)[1]','nvarchar(255)') 
FROM @XML.nodes(@Xpath) a(e)
```

Можно ли как-нибудь задать XPath через переменную, а не явно?

Можно конечно через `sp_executesql` сгенерировать запрос, но можно ли без этого?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать переменную *в качестве XPath* нельзя. [Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188282.aspx) на этот счёт строгa:

> Синтаксис: nodes (XQuery) as Table(Column)
>
> Аргументы:
>
> XQuery **Строковый литерал** ...

Попытка сделать это вызывает ошибку `Msg 8172`:

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string
>   literal.

Но можно использовать переменные *внутри XPath*.

Например, вместо

```
declare @xml xml = '<nodes><a id="1"/><b id="2"/></nodes>';
declare @path varchar(100);

set @path = '/nodes/b';

select x.c.value('@id', 'int') as id
from @xml.nodes(@path) x(c);

set @path = '/nodes/a';

select x.c.value('@id', 'int') as id
from @xml.nodes(@path) x(c);
```

можно использовать

```
declare @xml xml = '<nodes><a id="1"/><b id="2"/></nodes>';
declare @nodeName varchar(20);

set @nodeName = 'a';

select x.c.value('@id', 'int') as id
from @xml.nodes('/nodes[1]/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeName")]') x(c);

set @nodeName = 'b';

select x.c.value('@id', 'int') as id
from @xml.nodes('/nodes[1]/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@nodeName")]') x(c);
```